# on duplicate key primary key auto increment

Tags: php, innodb

I have used on duplicate key in my one project. But when all rows are already there and no data to update then also it increments auto_increment counter. So, previous auto_increment = 5 and after execution of on duplicate key query it automatically increments auto_increment counter = 6. So, my entries in table becomes, 

`id
__
1 
2 
3 
4 
6`

There is one solution for "innodb_autoinc_lock_mode" in my.ini but without changing and settings in my.ini, is there any other way I can manage autoincrement using php code only?

---

```
id  name    email
1   name1   name1@mail.com
3   name3   name3@mail.com
```

I have this table. where id is primarykey and email is uniqueId. Now where i run on duplicate key update with values(name1,name1@mail.com), so,this query will not update or create new entry because it's already existed. but auto_increment counter becomes 3. so, for next insert operation new id is 3.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with that behaviour? ID's are not supposed to "look nice".

Comment: Can you show that "on duplicate key" syntax? the auto-increment fields shoulnd't change on updates except if you are using REPLACE or manually bumpin them.

Comment: @amenadiel I believe the OP doesn't mean "my table changes" but the auto_increment value changes for the next `INSERT` after the key collision.

Comment: INSERT INTO table (id,a,b,c) VALUES (NULL,1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=values(a), b=values(b), c=values(c).
where a is unique_id.

Comment: I'm afraid that's the expected behaviour for auto_increment fields when performing on duplicate key update for innoDB. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @amenadiel that is innoDB's default behavior that's fine. Now, is there any way to avoid that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use php code to manage your ids then don't use auto increment at all.

Set the id manually by incrementing the max id value (obtained by using select max()...).